# How to disable restart print job which goes to error state?

Tags: windows, printing, printer

At windows 10 print spooling is enabled. When I print a multi-page document of 10 pages then after printing some pages like 5 pages if USB connection disconnected and connected again then it starts printing again from the very first page of the document, where it prints 5 pages already. Finally, it prints total 15 pages.

How to stop printing from the very first page of a broken job?

It happens for most of the printer at Windows operating system. Happen at both USB and Lan connnection connect/reconnet condition of the printer.

Comment: How can USB disconnect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Windows notices the printer has disappeared it puts the current print job on hold. At that stage the printer has not yet notified Windows that the print job has been completed. Then, when the printer becomes available again, Windows does not know have many pages have been physically printed. As a result, the only safe option is to start from page 1 again.

There are 2 things you can do.

1. Instead of disconnecting the printer, press the STOP or CANCEL button on your printer. Most printers have one, it's usually red. The printer will then stop printing, but accept the rest of the job from the PC, so that Windows thinks the job has been successfully printed.
2. If you did disconnect the printer, before reconnecting it double-click the printer icon in the taskbar. Then select the job and press the Delete key (or click on Document > Cancel) to remove the print job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it would better if there had any option at windows so that print spooler will not restart any broken job. Then we would configure that as our need.

Comment: Well, Windows also gives you the option of cancelling the job while it's being sent to the printer. That can be done at any time until the printer has accepted the entire job. The problem is that the printer may lag way behind Windows. For example, if the printer has to print 100 copies of every page in a 10 page job, it may still be working on page 1 when it has already received page 10.